# Can't play instagram videos on Chromium

Tags: video, flash, chromium, instagram

I can play instagram's videos on firefox, but can't on Chromium. I have no issue with other videos on youtube and facebook. The problem only occurs on instagram videos on Chromium (maybe vines too?).
I use adobe-flasplugin instead of pepperflash. Previously I have problem with facebook video and install pepperflash solve it. But now, I uninstall the pepperflash, facebook videos still working but it is not working with instagram videos.

Did I miss some configuration or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved by installing chromium codecs ffmpeg extra,

```
sudo apt install chromium-codecs-ffmpeg-extra
```

Thanks for your attention.